# Dell Zino HD: Is there space for a second HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, dell-inspiron

Can find anything for sure in Dell's site.
Before buying an external eSata Disc I want to know if it's possible to add a second HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, misunderstood. The answer is no, see this youtube video. I'm surprised it uses a full sized HDD at all. That uses up all of the room. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLBGNzYUYw8

Comment: Strange that the didn't use the smaller 2.5" or 1.8"

Answer (score 0):

I don't own one but looking at this pic, I see two e-sata ports in the back. So I'm gonna say yes. http://webtrickz.com/dell-inspiron-zino-hd-specifications-price/

Comment: My question is about adding the HDD **inside** the PC.